# tornadoweb upload to another server blocking process

Tags: upload, tornado, multipart

I created uploader from tornadoweb to another server. It block the process so I have to wait until all upload process finished to access another url (ShowQueue class) 
this is my code

```
    def create_callback(encoder,fileurl):
        encoder_len = encoder.len
        queueupload[fileurl] = {}
        queueupload[fileurl]["size"] = encoder_len

        def callback(monitor):
            queueupload[fileurl]["current"] = monitor.bytes_read
            # print queueupload
            # bar.show(monitor.bytes_read)
        return callback

class ShowQueue(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        self.write(tornado.escape.json_encode({'success':True,'queuelist':queueupload}))

class UploadFile(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        fileurl=self.get_argument("fileurl", None)
        taxo=self.get_argument("taxonomi", None)
        try:
            filename = fileurl.split("\\")[-1]
            # print filename
            encoder = MultipartEncoder({
                'taxonomi': taxo,
                'myFile': (filename, open(fileurl, 'rb'), 'text/plain'),
                })

            callback = create_callback(encoder,fileurl)
            monitor = MultipartEncoderMonitor(encoder, callback)
            if(taxo!=""):
                arrtaxo = taxo.split("/")
                taxo = ":".join(arrtaxo)
                taxo = "/"+taxo
            r = requests.post('http://192.168.123.123:8080/upload'+taxo, data=monitor,
                              headers={'Content-Type': monitor.content_type})
            if fileurl in queueupload:
                del queueupload[fileurl]
            self.write(tornado.escape.json_encode({'success':True,'reason':r.json()}))
        except Exception as e:
            exc = 'Exception: %s %s' % (e, filename)
            self.set_status(500)
            self.write(json_encode({'success':False,'exception':exc}))
```

How do I create uploader work asynchronously without blocking all process and still have control to cancel (I use callback to cancel process but not implemented yet)?

Answer (score 0):

The "requests" library isn't built for Tornado; it isn't async. Use Tornado's own AsyncHTTPClient instead:

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient

```
http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
r = yield http_client.fetch(url, method="post", ...)
```

Comment: I use
            with open(fileurl, 'r') as f:
                body = f.read()

            response = yield httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient().fetch('http://192.168.174.129:8080/upload'+taxo,method="POST",headers={"Content-Type": "text/plain"},body={"myFile":body})

but I got error Exception: Expected bytes, unicode, or None; got <type 'dict'>